# ImageMagick - how to enforce min/max heights/widths?

Tags: unix, command-line, imagemagick

Using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), how can I resize an image to have a **minimum**:

- height of 150px
- width of 200px

and *also* have a **maximum**:

- height of 225px
- width of 275px

**UPDATE**:

In case it helps, here's a further explanation of what I'm experiencing.

I have a buch of images with all different ratio dimensions. Some images have 1:5 height/width ratios. Some have 5:1 height/width ratios. So that I want to do is set that a minimum height/width size for the image but also don't want the image size to be larger than a particular size.

If I need to apply white padding to an image to make it fit within my constraint so that I don't have to distort the image, I'd like to do so.

Comment: What would be the actual resizing factor that you would be using? A percentage? I mean, you can't tell ImageMagick to resize an image to a value *between* two values - you would have to specify at least one, wouldn't you?

Comment: I have a buch of images with all different ratio dimensions. Some images have 1:5 height/width ratios. Some have 5:1 height/width ratios. So that I want to do is set that a minimum, the height/width is X BUT ALSO, don't let height/width get crazy large & out of control so I want to cap the height/width - even if that means  filling the image with white space to make the image fit within these contraints.

Answer (score 16):

I can't entirely get my head around your requirement, but I think this should be possible if you run IM twice.

See the manual on [geometry options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php?ImageMagick=45bcl1a3agvbinon3bgbll7l16#geometry):

A combination of

> **widthxheight>** Change as per widthxheight but only if an image dimension exceeds a specified dimension.

and

> **widthxheight^**     Minimum values of width and height given, aspect ratio preserved.

might do the trick. However, for images whose aspect ratio lies outside your requirements, I think you will have to create a fixed size canvas in IM, fill it with some colour, insert the image, and do a `trim()` on it... Probably not possible in one go, though.

Comment: So what would the command line code look like?  *convert widthxheight^=200x150 widthxheight=275x225*

Comment: @HenryH I don't think it works that way. You would have to make two runs on every image, one time bringing it up to the minimum size (if necessary) one time bringing it down (if necessary).

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer post to have the code necessary to do this. thanks

Comment: @HenryH sorry, I don't have Imagemagick handy right now to try out what sequence exactly is necessary (I would have to trial and error, too, I don't work with IM that often). Maybe somebody else can come up with it.

Comment: @HenryH the basic idea, though, just to be clear, is to call `convert` twice on the same image. Once to bring it to minimum size, one to cut it down to maximum size. That should be pretty straight forward to do.

Comment: Ex.: `-resize "1200x1200^"`

Answer (score 10):

Using ImageMagick you need only two `mogrify` passes: one to enlarge the ones smaller than your required minimum and one to shrink the ones that are larger than the maximum. For instance, to batch resize a bunch of JPEGs:

```
mogrify '*.jpg[!200x150<]'
mogrify '*.jpg[!275x225>]'
```

The first pass enlarges the ones smaller than 200x150 and the second one shrinks the ones larger than 275x225 (yes, the signs are correct!). `mogrify` replaces the original images, *which is what you need to do in this case*, to avoid resizing the images all over again in each pass and ending up with two processed copies.

Even though they are two passes you process every image only once (almost, see below). The first processes *x*% of the images and the other pass processes the remaining 100-*x*% (plus *c*, see below), assuming all images needed to be resized.

The ! is used to force change of aspect for images that are outside the range (our constant *c*), such as an image that is 1200x100, which would not fit in either 275x225 nor 200x150. These images  *will be processed twice*: in the first pass the aspect below the range (height or width) will  be augmented to the minimum, and on the second pass the other aspect will be reduced to the maximum.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

OK, I do some similar processing.  I don't have a generic solution for arbitrary sizes and aspect ratios, but if your input set of images is either 1:5 or 5:1, you can group them into 2 categories and process accordingly using some of these code snippets.

Step 1: determine which aspect ratio the image is, and based on that, set your target final altered dimensions.

```
INPATH="path/to/your_file.jpg"
DIMS=`identify "${INPATH}" | awk '{print $3}'`
WIDTH=`echo "${DIMS}"| cut -dx -f1`
HEIGHT=`echo "${DIMS}"| cut -dx -f2`
if (( ${WIDTH} > ${HEIGHT} ));
then
    #file is in landscape orientation
    THUMBDIM="80x60"
    WEBDIM="624x480"
else
    #file is in portrait orientation
    echo -n "(Portrait orientation) "
    THUMBDIM="60x80"
    WEBDIM="480x624"
fi
```

Step 2, do the actual resize:

```
convert "${INPATH}" -resize "${THUMBDIM}" "resized-${INPATH}"
```

This sample assumes a fixed set of desired sizes, but of course you could do some basic arithmetic using your original dimensions as input and scaling up in proportion to fit within your stated boundaries.

Comment: The line `if [[ ${WIDTH} > ${HEIGHT} ]]` made an alphabetical comparison, so that 1000 < 800. I replaced it to a numerical comparison.

Comment: Not sure if all shells will have that kind of arithmetic evaluation (since the original question is tagged `unix` and not `bash` or `macos` or `linux`), but `[ "$WIDTH" -gt "$HEIGHT" ]` should be portable. Note the quotes around the variables, which are not required with the Bash shell's `[[ ]]` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on above:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$1"
DIMS=`identify "${FILE}" | awk '{print $3}'`
WIDTH=`echo "${DIMS}"| cut -dx -f1`
HEIGHT=`echo "${DIMS}"| cut -dx -f2`
max_w=2000
max_h=2000

if [[ $HEIGHT -gt $max_h ]]; then
    WIDTH=$(( $WIDTH * $max_h / $HEIGHT ))
    HEIGHT="$max_h"
fi


if [[ $WIDTH -gt $max_w ]]; then
    HEIGHT=$(( $HEIGHT * $max_w / $WIDTH ))
    WIDTH="$max_w"
fi

echo "$FILE ${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}"
mogrify -filter Lanczos -resize "${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}" "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html) that is a part of the imagemagick suite.

There is an example of how to use it [here](http://cubiq.org/create-fixed-size-thumbnails-with-imagemagick)